# Convert patient coordinates into voxel coordinates for DICOM images

Tags: python, image-processing, voxel, medical, medical-imaging

I have a question pertaining to the conversion of patient coordinates into `voxel coordinates` of a `3D MRI point cloud` model obtained from `DICOM`. I have a 3D point cloud file obtained from 2D MRI images, and the points are in the patient coordinate system. I am trying to convert those points in the cloud into `voxel coordinates` using the inverse of an affine matrix that I had initially created. But the affine matrix I have is singular and hence I cannot directly apply the inverse function on it. Is there a way to either construct an inverse affine matrix without applying the inverse function on the affine matrix?  Or is there any other way to implement this conversion? I have also tried to get the pseudo-inverse matrix from the affine matrix, but I am not sure if that would help in any way.

I am working in `Python 3.7`. The shape of the affine matrix is `(160, 4, 4)`, that of the pseudo-inverse matrix is also `(160, 4, 4)`, and that of the point cloud array is `(2086604, 4)`.

To convert to voxel coordinates, the code and resulting shape of the array are as follows:

```
voxels = np.dot(p_inverse_whole, stack_patient.T)  
(160, 4, 2086604)
```

Ideally I would like to have the resulting array in the following shape: `(160, 4, 4)` instead of `(160, 4, 2086604)`

Could anyone of you please help me solving this problem?

Comment: @Ashrita Eadara I'm facing a related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471317/how-to-use-the-dicom-affine-transformation-matrix-to-convert-patient-coordinates Did you manage to find a solution?